# ta.barssince for multi-time frame analysis

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm counting on an hourly time frame the bars since the last event a condition was met. Works nicely.

```
ta.barssince(cond == true)
```

I want to do the same in the same strategy for a multi-timeframe. e.g. on a daily TF. How do I get around the fact that `ta.barssince` does not offer this for another time-frame than the selected one?

The only thing I can think of is to multiply all the values I have by 24.

Any smart workarounds and better ideas than the 24x?

(in case you are curious what I try to achieve: I'm trying to locate pivot points in a multi-timeframe analysis. That is hourly and daily. Thus I can incorporate bearish divergence on all levels to avoid buying in too early.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate `barssince()` expression in scope of another chart TF by using `request.security()` function:

```
//@version=5
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=false, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

cond = ta.barssince(close>open)
plot(cond) // current TF
s = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", cond) 
plot(s, color = color.red)   // 1H
```